# Unable to ‎WebKit Layout Tests‎ on android

Tags: android, testing, layout, webkit, chromium

- Compile the chromium for Android
  Build every test:

`$ ninja -C out/Release`

- Running the layout Tests

`$ webkit/tools/layout_tests/run_webkit_tests.sh`

I get following errors:

> Using port 'chromium-linux-x86_64' Test configuration:  Placing test results in
>   /host/chromium/src/webkit/Release/layout-test-results Baseline search
>   path: chromium-linux -> chromium-win -> generic Using Release build
>   Pixel tests enabled Regular timeout: 6000, slow test timeout: 30000
>   Command line:
>   /host/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/out/Release/DumpRenderTree -
>
> Found 29487 tests; running 28395, skipping 1092. Unable to find test
>   driver
>       at /host/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/out/Release/DumpRenderTree
>
> For complete Linux build requirements, please see:
>
> http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions
>   Build check failed

Answer (score 0):

Support for layout tests on Android is being worked on at the moment. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232044